# Getting index of special pixel (x and y position) or transform lat/lon of pixel to index in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, coordinates, spatial-index

I am trying to find the index (x and y pixel position in an image) of a pixel (ex: the pixel with max DN value). however, it has been challenging for me.

My code is:

```
var geometry3 = 
   ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[52.35358322183839, 30.040032719852206],
          [52.35358322183839, 29.729264595699064],
          [53.16519821207277, 29.729264595699064],
          [53.16519821207277, 30.040032719852206]]], null, false);

var AOI=geometry3;
Map.centerObject(AOI,10);
var start_date= "2019-01-01";
var end_date= "2020-01-01";
//////////////////////////////// LANDSAT data ////////////////////////////////
var collection= ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
              .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(AOI))
              .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_date,end_date))
               .filter(ee.Filter.lte("CLOUD_COVER_LAND",20))
               .median();
var image =  collection.clip(AOI)              
print(image)

// print(image_median,"image_median")

var RGB_visparam= {
        bands:["B5","B4","B3"],
        min:850,
        max:3300};

Map.addLayer(image, RGB_visparam)  


var B5 = image.select("B5");
print(B5)

var B5_max = B5.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: AOI,
  scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
  bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
});
print(B5_max)
```

Or if i have a point coordinate of a pixel (ex: `var point = ee.Geometry.Point([52.35358322183839,30.040032719852206]);`)

How can I transform the coordinate to x/y position?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ee.Image.pixelLonLat()` for this; this is an image with two bands named 'longitude' and 'latitude'. You can mask this image with the value from your reducer ('B5_max'), to return only pixels that equal this value.

```
var lonlat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()
      .updateMask(B5.eq(ee.Image((ee.Number(B5_max)))))
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
        geometry: AOI,
        scale: 30,
        maxPixels: 1e9,
        bestEffort: true,
        tileScale: 16
      });
```

This returns two lists; i.e. the coordinates of the two pixels that equal 'B5_max':

```
print(lonlat);
latitude: [30.027221434271745,30.027221434271745]
longitude: [52.945310457314214,52.945579951899454]
```

Please note that you're using the `ee.Reducer.min()` reducer - this returns the minimum not maximum value (which seems to be the value you're interested in?).

Comment: thanks a lot... and one more question...how can i find x/y index of the pixel based on this coordinate?